node.js v18 using babel - how to import module with extension and how to run from build folder (commonJS) while type:module is in package.json
I am using Node.JS v18.20.4 with Babel.
Here is my babel.config.json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": 18
        },
        "debug": true,
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": "3.37.1"
      }
    ]
  ]
}

Here is my package.json
"main": "src/app.js",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "npm run build && node build/app.js",
  "build": "eslint src && babel src -d build --source-maps",
  "dev": "nodemon src/app.js"
},
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.37.1",
    "express": "^4.19.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.24.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.8",
    "@eslint/js": "^9.7.0",
    "eslint": "^9.7.0",
    "globals": "^15.8.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.4",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3"
  }

Here is npm start output.
[vagrant@linuxbox api]$ npm start

> xxxx_api@1.0.0 start
> npm run build && node build/app.js


> xxxx_api@1.0.0 build
> eslint src && babel src -d build --source-maps

@babel/preset-env: `DEBUG` option

Using targets:
{
  "node": "18"
}

Using modules transform: auto

Using plugins:
  transform-unicode-sets-regex { node < 20 }
  syntax-class-static-block
  syntax-private-property-in-object
  syntax-class-properties
  syntax-numeric-separator
  syntax-nullish-coalescing-operator
  syntax-optional-chaining
  syntax-json-strings
  syntax-optional-catch-binding
  syntax-async-generators
  syntax-object-rest-spread
  proposal-export-namespace-from { }
  transform-modules-commonjs
  proposal-dynamic-import
  syntax-top-level-await
  syntax-import-meta
corejs3: `DEBUG` option

Using targets: {
  "node": "18"
}

Using polyfills with `usage-global` method:

[/home/vagrant/xxxx/api/src/app.js]
Based on your code and targets, the corejs3 polyfill did not add any polyfill.

[/home/vagrant/xxxx/api/src/routes.js]
Based on your code and targets, the corejs3 polyfill did not add any polyfill.
Successfully compiled 2 files with Babel (1063ms).
file:///home/vagrant/xxxx/api/build/app.js:3
var _express = _interopRequireDefault(require("express"));
               ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/home/vagrant/xxxx/api/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///home/vagrant/xxxx/api/build/app.js:3:16
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:195:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:34:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:106:12)

Node.js v18.20.4

and using nodemon
vagrant@linuxbox api]$ npm run dev

> work_management_api@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon src/app.js

[nodemon] 3.1.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node src/app.js`
node:internal/errors:496
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/home/vagrant/xxxx/api/src/routes' imported from /home/vagrant/xxxx/api/src/app.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:327:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:980:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1206:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:404:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:373:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:250:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  url: 'file:///home/vagrant/xxxx/api/src/routes',
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v18.20.4
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Here is my app.js file look like
import express from 'express';
import routes from './routes';
// Creating express object
const app = express();

If I add .js explicitly like route.js on this line      import routes from './routes.js';
Then my nodemon src/app.js command using npm run dev works fine. but I don't want to use .js extension, Am I missing any configuration anywhere so it is not required?
If I add .js as above or not, npm start (npm run build && node build/app.js) still fails.
But if I change it to npm run build && node src/app.js and add .js explicitly, it also works.

How can I eliminate .js when importing my modules?
How can I run the npm run build && node build/app.js from the build folder which I believe babel has converted it to commonjs but because package.json has "type": "module" in it, it is throwing an error. If I remove that it throws an error that either I need to have mjs extension or "type": "module" in package.json.


This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file
extension and '/home/vagrant/xxxx/api/package.json' contains "type":
"module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the
'.cjs' file extension.

It has become a catch-22 for me. :)
Any help would be appreciated.
REF: Exclude files from type: module without changing file extension

Solution:

Add .js extension when importing modules
Remove "type":"module" from
package.json and add --experimental-default-type=module where needed

package.json
  "main": "src/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm run build && node build/app.js",
    "build": "eslint src && babel src -d build --source-maps",
    "dev": "nodemon --experimental-default-type=module src/app.js"
  },

app.js
import express from 'express';
import routes from './routes.js';

const app = express();

Description:
It seems like an extension is needed when importing a module. (There may be a workaround I am unaware of at this stage.)

"A file extension must be provided when using the import keyword to
resolve relative or absolute specifiers. Directory indexes (e.g.
'./startup/index.js') must also be fully specified."

Ref: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-specifiers
Ref: How to import an es module in Node without an extension
Secondly,
Instead of putting the type":"module" in the package.json file to activate it globally, you could use --experimental-default-type=module only where needed.
Ref: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--experimental-default-typetype
If anyone has a better solution, please advise.
